# Implement string identifier for Java Colour class

Tags: java, colors

I'm trying to create a Colour class.
When creating my Colour object, exactly 3 colour components are required.
My object can't be created without specifying exact values for these components.
Valid values will be in the range 0-255.
The given values would be stored directly rather than converting between colour modules (RGB/HSV/etc..)

The default colour module will be RGB.
Different colour modules (eg, HSV) will have to be specified by using a String value to identify the name of the model.

To implement my string identifier I'd set it as a private attribute, then create a setter/getter method for for public access.

It would need a check that’s it’s a string, non-empty, strip white space from it.
Would that be the right implementation?

Comment: One way to help clarify your thinking is to get rid of generic pronouns like "it" from your language. Instead use the specific word that "it" refers to. So instead of writing ""I’d have it as a private attribute", state specificially what that private attribute is.

Comment: Good point, thanks I'll try take that on board from now on!

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your question according to this tip to make it (your question) more clear.

Comment: "I want to be able to specify a different colour model by using a String value to identify the name of the model when creating the Colour object." What do you mean by this? What kinds of string values are allowed? Clarifying these details will help you work towards the implementation.

Comment: Hopefully my edit helps with the explanation, sorry for being unclear, I'm not great at explanations.

Comment: So what private attributes will you need? Will you store the given values directly (whether it is RGB or HSV or CMYK) or will you the given values to a canonical form (for example convert everything to RGB)?

Comment: I'd probably store the given values directly. 
I'm not 100% sure about the private attributes as that's just my current guess at how to implement the string identifier.

Comment: You should use an enum rather than private members.

Comment: Why not use the already existing java Color class?

Comment: @NomadMaker enum and private members are not mutually exclusive. It sounds like this is a learning exercise.

Comment: @Partypaul32 So you need private variables for anything you need to store. Can you be more specific about what exactly these will be?

Comment: The problem with using private attributes for these strings is that outside classes need to know them. To change the color to "red" I need to know the string "red."

Comment: @NomadMaker
I'd say I would use the Colour class alright, I still get caught with the String identifier implementation for it. Yeah I get what you're saying about the attributes.

Comment: What you should be using is simply an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).